# genus-zero Gromov-Witten invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a complex $n$-dimensional  Hermitian symmetric space of compact type, where $\omega$ is the symplectic (Kaehler) form on $M$ normalized so that $[\omega]$ generates  the integral cohomology class $H^2(M, Z)$. Let $A$ be the generator of $H_2(M, Z)$.

Problem: Find  two submanifolds $X$ and $Y$ of $M$ such that:
$$\dim_{\R} X+\dim_{\R} Y=4n-2c_1(TM)(A)$$
and
$$\Phi_A([X], [Y], [p])\neq 0,$$
where $\Phi_A([X], [Y], [p])$ is the genus-zero Gromov--Witten invariant of the triple $[p], [X], [Y]$ and $[p]$, $[X]$ and $[Y]$ denote   the homology classes of  a point $p\in M$,  $X$ and $Y$ respectively.)

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  There is a classification of irreducible, compact Hermitian symmetric spaces.  There is also a theorem of Koll&aacute;r and Ruan that guarantees the existence of a nonzero, one-point Gromov-Witten invariant.  In principle, you could go through the list and find nonzero Gromov-Witten invariants in each case (simplified by the many results of experts such as Buch-Kresch-Tamvakis on GW theory of homogeneous spaces).  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you  for your answer.
Yes I think you answer to my question. 
My problem was  the following (with the same notation as in my question).
Let J be  an  almost complex structure of  M  tamed by \omega and p be a point of  M.  Does there exists a J-holomorphic curve in the class of A which pass through p?

Therefore, if I can find a non-zero  one-point genus-zero Gromov-Witten invariant I believe I can giva a positiva answer to my question. Thank you 


Answer (score 2):

I will just consider the simplest example, maybe someone will give the answer in complete generality. 
So let $M=\mathbb CP^n$. Then $4n-2c_1(M)(A)=2n-2$. This means that we are in good shape. Basically we can take for $X$ and $Y$ any complex submanifolds of $M$ satisfying your condition. Indeed in this case for a generic point $p$ in $\mathbb CP^n$ there will be $deg X\cdot deg Y$ lines that contain $p$ and intersect both $X$ and $Y$. I assumed  $X$ (or $Y$) is not zero dimensional, in which case there is only one line and also that $X$ and $Y$ are in general position, but this does not matter for GW, of course.